# Cite a paper by DOI

Tags: publications, citations, journals, online-publication, doi

I would like to cite a paper in the reference of my paper. However, the paper I want to cite is online published by a journal for the time being, and has not been assigned to an issue yet.

If I cite the paper by its DOI number, that is, "name of the author, title of the paper, name of the journal, DOI: XXXXXXXXXX", will this citation be calculated into the number of the citation by Journal Citation Reports (JCR)?

Comment: So the article in question has been accepted, has a DOI, appears on the journal homepage, but has yet to be printed? In that case I'd use the "forthcoming" as the year. For instance: "Author name(s). Title. Journal in question (forthcoming).
doi:XXXXXXXX". I do not know the answer to the the question about the JCR.

Comment: You could contact the authors of the paper they might know better what to do.

Comment: Are you submitting your paper to a journal (or conference proceedings or similar)? The journal most probably has rules for formatting reference lists, and citing a paper before it gets assigned page numbers is common enough for them to have exact instructions, so you don't have a lot of choice in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The Journal Citation Reports (JCR) are a byproduct of Clarivate Analytics' Web of Science. Hence, citations that are in Web of Science are also counted in the JCR. So, your question boils down to this: if you cite a work that has not been formally published yet, will it be recognized as such in Web of Science?

The citation matching algorithm of Web of Science is a company secret, as far as I'm aware, so I canot give a definitive answer. In my personal experience (for what it's worth), citations to unpublished work (mentioning all bibliographic details, including DOI) are usually recognized if the publication year is correct. This is sometimes hard because publication delays may take up to (or more than) a year.

What can you do? First, make sure that all verifiable details in your reference are correct, including author names, journal, title and DOI. Second, if it eventually turns out that Web of Science did not process the citation link between your paper and the one cited correctly, there is an easy solution: you can [ask for a correction](http://ips.clarivate.com/support/faq/datachanges/). If DOIs and other metadata match, then this is typically no problem. It may take a few weeks before the request is processed though.